# Activate Marketing Automation campaigns in Sitecore 9.1 is giving us “api 404 error”

Tags: marketing-automation

[image]

When i activate the Marketing automation campaigns this error appear

> "The requested resource was not found."

This issue appears after an upgrade from Sitecore 9.0 to 9.1. I compared the configs and dlls with a clean instance and they all the same.

Comment: Is there any Sitecore error logs .?

Comment: Also you migrated from Sitecore 9.0 to 9.1 and looks like you verified the config files. Did you check the DB as well, there are few DB scripts which you might have executed to upgrade the xConnect, verify that as well.

Comment: there is no errors in the log
also i execute all the upgrade scripts but i will do it again

Comment: are you trying this in a distributed environment.? explain further about the how these are setup.

Comment: Had a similar issue, check if all Activity Types have an Icon assigned. /sitecore/system/settings/Analytics/Marketing Automation/Activity Types/Campaign Entry

Comment: There's a connection to xConnect that MA needs. The 404 error is probably a bad URL to xConnection Marketing Operations URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced that the initial `POST` request works but but the following `PUT` and `PATCH` requests fails with `404 NotFound`. 
The `AutomationPlansController` in Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Client uses AutomationPlanRepository to find the plan, and if it is not found 404 is returned.
The result is that if there is anything wrong with xConnect or SolR connection or schema, marketing definitions, etc., we will get this 404 error and there aren't really any usefull log entries.

I had errors in SolR and a custom computed field, I could see that in the Crawling log but not while this method failed. When the error was fixed I could repopulate SolR schema and depoloy market definitions, then the save and update operations worked.

Also note that those endpoints requires that you have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests enabled in your web.config (we usually disable that for increased performance:

```xml
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```